# How to change widget title in wordpress version 5.8.1?

Tags: widgets, widget-text

Maybe this is a novice question but I am stumped. I am trying to change the title of a widget (recent posts) in WordPress 5.8.1 version. I have installed WordPress after a long time again and can not seem to find the option to change a widget title. How to do this? Please remember that I do not want to change the title programmatically as I can do that. Just want an easy point and click option like the old WordPress. I have attached a screenshot of the widget admin screen. [image]Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customising widget titles/headings in WP 5.8](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/393729/customising-widget-titles-headings-in-wp-5-8)

Comment: Thanks but I can change stuff programmatically and was looking for a way to do this without coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress 5.8 the ability to add Blocks to widget areas, and several core widgets were replaced with Blocks. Blocks do not have a standardised title field. So to add titles you will need to use a heading bock, and for any blocks that do have a title, whether or how a title can be changed would depend entirely on the block.

Comment: Thats more like it. I was wondering if I was missing something obvious. Thanks.